# How do I use REGEXP in MariaDB to find a specific pattern of usernames in my database

Tags: sql, regex, mariadb

So I'm trying to find usernames that match a certain pattern, basically to exclude them from my query since those who follow that pattern are essentially automatically generated inactive users.

So here it goes.

These usernames follow this pattern: userID@accountID. So they can look something like this:

```
1@1234
```

The user ID can be anywhere from 1 to 3 digits long and the account ID can be anywhere from 2 to 5 digits long.

I've tried to do this, which I've found on another thread, but I think it only works for **MySQL** and not **MariaDB**.

```
SELECT ...

FROM   ...

WHERE  username.Username NOT LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]\{1\}@[0-9]\{1\}$' OR #For X@X
       username.Username NOT LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]\{2\}@[0-9]\{1\}$' OR #For XX@X
       username.Username NOT LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]\{3\}@[0-9]\{1\}$' OR #For XXX@X
       username.Username NOT LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]\{1\}@[0-9]\{2\}$' OR #For X@XX
       username.Username NOT LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]\{2\}@[0-9]\{2\}$' OR #For XX@XX
       username.Username NOT LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]\{3\}@[0-9]\{2\}$' OR #For XXX@XX
       username.Username NOT LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]\{1\}@[0-9]\{3\}$' OR #For X@XXX
       username.Username NOT LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]\{2\}@[0-9]\{3\}$' OR #For XX@XXX
       username.Username NOT LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]\{3\}@[0-9]\{3\}$' OR #For XXX@XXX
       username.Username NOT LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]\{1\}@[0-9]\{4\}$' OR #For X@XXXX
       username.Username NOT LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]\{2\}@[0-9]\{4\}$' OR #For XX@XXXX
       username.Username NOT LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]\{3\}@[0-9]\{4\}$' OR #For XXX@XXXX
       username.Username NOT LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]\{1\}@[0-9]\{5\}$' OR #For X@XXXXX
       username.Username NOT LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]\{2\}@[0-9]\{5\}$' OR #For XX@XXXXX
       username.Username NOT LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]\{3\}@[0-9]\{5\}$'    #For XXX@XXXXX
```

And it obviously doesn't work, hense why I'm asking the question here.

So my question is, what would the proper format be? Also, is there a way to not have 15 conditions and format the REGEXP so that only one condition does the work?

Comment: Perhaps try `^[0-9]{1,3}@[0-9]{2,5}$` https://regex101.com/r/wGn9Oh/1

Comment: Which version of MariaDB are you running?

Comment: @GMB It is 10.2.27

Comment: @Thefourthbird It worked, but I also had to remove the LIKE in the expression.  
For future reference, it's:  
  
`WHERE username.Username NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,3}@[0-9]{2,5}$'`  
  
and not:  
  
`WHERE username.Username NOT LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,3}@[0-9]{2,5}$'`

Comment: @G.Langlois Glad you have resolved the issue :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax is `<expr> not regex <regex>` (there is no `like` involved, neither in MySQL nor in MariaDB).

You would need to get rid of these backslashes. Also, you can use pairs of numbers (separated by a comma) as quantifiers to define the minimum and maximum number of matches. This lets you use a single condition, like:

```
where username not regexp '^[0-9]{1,3}@[0-9]{2,5}$'
```

This [seems to work in MariaDB 10.2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=64ff063f52fa2464e10d97ac51c0e05d).

Comment: Alright, so this worked. I've done:

`WHERE username.Username NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,3}@[0-9]{2,5}$'`

and got the desired results. Thank you very much!